# Многомерный массив c#

Tags: c#, массивы

Есть 2 строки в файле вида

4

1,4,2,1

Где первая строка - кол-во "лаб". А вторая - кол-во "заданий" в каждой. 
Крч нужно создать многомерный массив, чтобы каждый каждый элемент можно было изменить(каждое "задание" оценить).

Как это можно сделать? Я пытался так, но не вышло

```
int[,] arr = new int[a,]  a=4
for (int i=0;i<arr.Length;i++)
int[i]=new int[b[i]];  b[i]-элемент из 1,4,2,1
```

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что вот это `new int[a,]` должно работать?

Comment: тут подсмотрел https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.4.php
ничего не работает, теперь даже не знаю, как массив такой сделать

Comment: [Массивы](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/). Прочтёте и всё поймёте.

Comment: Вообще основное, что нужно понимать: 1) Многомерные массивы `a[,]` инициализируются вводом сразу всех измерений. Это потому, что многомерный массив - это по сути обыкновенный одномерным массив, но с облегчённой индексацией. То есть в памяти он хранится, как одномерный массив. 2) Массив массивов `a[][]` - это самый обыкновенный одномерный массив, но не исходных элементов, а ссылок на массивы, поэтому там на начальном этапе требуется только инициализация одного измерения. То есть `a[][]` - это массив неких `b[]`, где уже лежат нужные элементы.

Answer (score 4):

Прямоугольные массивы:

```
// Объявление и создание массива:
int[,] array = new int[5, 10];
// Доступ к элементу
array[0, 0] = 10;
```

"Рваные" массивы (массивы массивов, по-сути):

```
// Объявление и создание массива:
int[][] array = new int[5][];
array[0] = new int[10];
array[1] = new int[8];
// Доступ к элементу
array[0][0] = 10;
```